# there is already an object named '' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier  -- creating table supplier
(
  supplierID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  supplierName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  suppplierNo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  supplierEmail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_supplierID PRIMARY KEY(supplierID)
)

GO
```

I get the the error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 34
>
> There is already an object named 'supplier' in the database.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Well, drop the table if you want a new version.  Or use `alter table`.  What part of the message do you not understand?

Comment: The existing object may not necessarily be a table but anyway the message seems clear. What are you asking us?

Comment: Error is about there a table object exist in the database with same name supplier so you can drop and create it

Comment: just a tip, avoid adding `supplier` to the whole fields.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i dont understand how the message appears theres already an object if i am just creating the table. I am fairly new to SQL keep that in mind ^^

Comment: What do you get back with this `select * from sys.objects o where o.[name]='supplier'`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if the table exists first

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.supplier', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.supplier;
CREATE TABLE dbo.supplier
(
    supplierID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    supplierName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    suppplierNo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    supplierEmail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_supplierID PRIMARY KEY(supplierID)
)
GO
```

If you are using 2016+ you can use

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.supplier;
CREATE TABLE dbo.supplier
(
    supplierID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    supplierName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    suppplierNo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    supplierEmail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_supplierID PRIMARY KEY(supplierID)
)
GO
```

Comment: Blindly dropping an existing table that may contain data may not be the best solution here

Comment: Also won't help if the existing object isn't a table. Blindly offering this advice I think is rather dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'supplier') 

DROP TABLE dbo.supplier;
CREATE TABLE dbo.supplier
(
    supplierID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    supplierName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    suppplierNo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    supplierEmail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_supplierID PRIMARY KEY(supplierID)
)
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

1.First Delete The Whole Data Base

2.Try To Changing Name of Db

3.Check Connection Make New File Ans Try Only This Block Of Code

Comment: Talk about sledgehammer approach.  This should not be necessary in the slightest